# how could I improve the appearance of ListView

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

Currently I face the following issue - I create a custom **ListView** (**1** x **ImageView** + **2** x **TextView**). It displays content from I-net, which is an *XML* file.

What am I doing - I'm using AsyncTask to run in background the process of downloading the *XML* content and filling up the **ListView** by calling ***publishProgress(...)*** method for each and every list item from ***doInBackground(...)*** method. When the ***doInBackground(...)*** completes I already had collected the *URL* of each and every image I want to display and then from ***onPostExecute(...)*** method I start download process for the images and update the *UI* for every downloaded image. The problem for me is that the **ListView** should fill up at least a few items before to start download an drawable file and update the list. Currently the **ListView** shows a single item and when fill next one, all images are already downloaded. I debug the app and I saw that one I stop in ***onPostExecute(...)*** method and want to take the number of **ListView** items, it's return just one, as it displays.

Is there a way to force appearance **Listview**'s items, before to start the download or this because the I-net connection, that I have, is gut enough and there is not delay by downloading the images.

I forget only to mention that each and every image is not bigger then a 10KB.

This is my custom **AsyncTask**:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, List<RSSItem>> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            la.clear();
        }
        protected List<RSSItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            parse(urls[0]);

            if (feed == null) { return null; }

            rssList = feed.getAllItems();
            Iterator<RSSItem> iterator = rssList.iterator();

            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                if (isCancelled()) return null; 
                RSSItem rss = iterator.next();
                publishProgress(rss);
            }

            return rssList;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

            la.add((RSSItem)progress[0]);
            la.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RSSItem> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Drawable downloadedImage;
            for (int z = 0; z < rssList.size(); z++) {
                downloadedImage = downloadImage(rssList.get(z).getImageURL());
                ((RSSItem)rssList.get(z)).setImage(downloadedImage);
                la.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }
    }
```

Here is the custom **Listadapter**:

```
private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

        private List<RSSItem> items;

        public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<RSSItem> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            RSSItem item = items.get(position);

            if (item != null) {
                ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
                if (item.getImage() != null) {
                    itemImage.setBackgroundDrawable(item.getImage());
                } else {
                    itemImage.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
                }
                if (title != null) {
                    title.setText(item.getTitle());
                }
                if (description != null) {
                    description.setText(item.getDescription());
                }
            }

            return v;
        }
    }
```

...and the **Item** class:

```
public class RSSItem {
    private String data = null;
    private String description = null;
    private Drawable image = null;
    private String imageUrl = null;
    private String title = null;

    RSSItem() {
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageUrl = imageURL;
    }

    public void setImage(Drawable image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Drawable getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

@MODIFICATIONS:

private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

```
        la.clear();
    }

    protected List<RSSItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        parse(urls[0]);

        if (feed == null) { return null; }

        rssList = feed.getAllItems();
        publishProgress(true);

        Drawable downloadedImage;
        for (int z = 0; z < rssList.size(); z++) {
            downloadedImage = downloadImage(rssList.get(z).getImageURL());
            ((RSSItem)rssList.get(z)).setImage(downloadedImage);
        }
        return rssList;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

        la.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<RSSItem> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        la.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your issue, but what I would do is the following (if I got it right):

I suppose you have a custom Object that you store in your ListView, let's say CustomItem.
I would place the download of the URL Image in the constructor of that object, and store the `Drawable` as a member of your CustomItem. And just after you have created a new `CustomItem` and got the image for it, `publishProgress()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your list adapter.

EDIT: You should move the code from the `onPostExecute()` method at the end of your `doInBackground()` method.

Try this:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, RSSItem, Void> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        la.clear();
    }
    protected List<RSSItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        parse(urls[0]);

        if (feed == null) { return null; }
        rssList = feed.getAllItems();
        Iterator<RSSItem> iterator = rssList.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (isCancelled()) return null; 
            RSSItem rss = iterator.next();
            //this happens fast no need to do this
            publishProgress(rss);
            //la.add(rss);
        }
        Drawable downloadedImage;
        for (int z = 0; z < rssList.size(); z++) {
            downloadedImage = downloadImage(rssList.get(z).getImageURL());
            ((RSSItem)rssList.get(z)).setImage(downloadedImage);
            publishProgress(null);
        }
        return rssList;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(RSSItem... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        if progress!=null
           la.add((RSSItem)progress[0]);
        la.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, you misunderstand what I want to do. First I've got already this that you're saying and it is working, but I do not want to download an image and populate it into the **ListView**. I want just to populate the text and there is a default static image which will appears instead the original one. After the **doInBackground** finishes it returns a value to **onPostExecute** and there I'm gonna do the download of all images. You can see it above through the source that I shared.

Comment: Ok. I got it now. The code in doBackground will finish real quick and the problem is that you execute the time consuming part of your code in the `postExecute()` which will run on the UIThread and will block your UI. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Do you mean to move the two lines of code from **onProgressUpdate(...)** to **doInBackground(...)** before `return` statement. If it is that, it generates an exception. Also I'm not sure that I can call **notifyDataSetChanged(...)** from **doInBackground(...)**, they are running on two different threats, respectevely **doInBackground(...)** - on Backgroud threat and **notifyDataSetChanged(...)** on UI threat

Comment: read my edit carefully. the code from onPostExecute move it in doInBackground too. And again try to call the onProgressUpdate() with a flag or something to know that you don't need to add an RssItem this time.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood about **onPostExecute(...)**, but still does't work, this time I don't use `la.add((RSSItem).....)` and there is nothing in the **ListView**! Could you demonstrate what exactly you have in mind? You also may want to see what I've done with the **AsyncTask** class? See @MODIFICATIONS >>

Comment: do you have items in your rssList or it is empty? maybe you have an error somewere else..

Comment: Exception at `la.add(rss);` and the List is filled up with data!

Answer (score 1):

Are you populating the underlying data set of your list adapter in `doInBackground()`?  Then, in addition to calling `publishProgress()`, you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onProgressUpdate()` of your `AsyncTask`.